# Add className onClick by item id

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Sure it is something simple but I cannot see where I have gone wrong here.

I am trying to add `className` `onClick` to a list from a `data.map`, taking note that `onClick` I only want the clicked `selectedId` to add the `className`

Here is where I am at

```
class Grid extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      selectedId: null,
    };
  }

  handleClick = selectedId => {
    this.setState({
      selectedId,
    });
  };

  render() {
    const childElements = this.props.amenitiesData.edges.map(
      ({ node: amenity }) => {
        const isActive = amenity.id === this.state.selectedId;
        const showCopy = isActive ? 'showCopy' : '';
        return (
          <div key={amenity.id} className="grid-item">
            <div className={`copy-wrapper ${showCopy}`}>
              <div className="expand-button">
                <a
                  href="#"
                  onClick={() => this.handleClick(amenity.id)}
                >
                  ...
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      }
    );

    return (
      <Wrapper>
        {childElements}
      </Wrapper>
    );
  }
}
```

The issue is that when I click on any given item, the `className` is of `showCopy` is not added.

Here is the current data structure for `amenity.id`. Passed from `parent` as `const amenitiesData = data.allContentfulAmenities;`

Please note that the data for each item in the list is correct with zero errors.

```
{
"data": {
    "allContentfulAmenities": {
      "edges": [
        {
          "node": {
            "id": "8e9e933d-0395-5867-9e30-1c46726766f2"
          }
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "id": "4e04401c-5bdd-5174-8a2c-ea1fc36c0cc4"
          }
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "id": "ce89e346-8136-5afa-966b-6eb7443d9272"
          }
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "id": "7a85ee22-6ec5-5a53-9e60-44012ad24130"
          }
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "id": "f56e28bb-e1ff-5b59-be3a-1fde9333c79d"
          }
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "id": "078753ed-e6b0-5770-9ba5-6cb025c3aa5a"
          }
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "id": "a48ad8df-d084-550b-91e9-e4804308c336"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It seems to work fine here, I made a fiddle with your example: https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/279474/

Are you sure that your `onClick` is getting triggered? Try outputting `amenity.id` and `this.state.selectedId` into your render function. Also, in your `onClick` you should add `e.preventDefault()` to prevent the default browser behavior of moving to the top of the screen.

Comment: outputting to your console, in your render function*

Comment: Thank you @inostia. Outputting `this.state.selectedId` returns as `null`, whilst `amenity.id` returns a list of all `id`. Bizarre that your fiddle works, whilst my app doesn't. Cheers.

Comment: I think maybe look at the data structure that I am passing as a `prop` to `Grid`. That is the data structure I would expect to see given the way you destructure it in your Grid render function. Good luck

Comment: Cheers Buddy. My first thought was to the data but looking at your fiddle, the structure is exact. Thanks for your help and have a good day.

Comment: I have edited my answer, Here is link to the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your render do this.

```
render() {
  const childElements = this.props.amenitiesData.edges.map(({ node: amenity }) => {
    return (
      <div key={amenity.id} className="grid-item">
        <div className={`
           copy-wrapper 
           ${amenity.id === this.state.selectedIdshowCopy ? showCopy' : ''}
        `}>
          <div className="expand-button">
            <a
              href="#"
              onClick={() => this.handleClick(amenity.id)}
            >
              ...
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
);
```

Previously the problem was once your selectedId matched with your `amenity.id` you toggle the `selectedIdshowCopy` to `true` which ended up adding the 'showCopy`to every item in your`.map()`

Answer (score -1):

You need to replace `<a>` tag with a div ( or a button) then bind a `onClick` listener. Currently your anchor tag has href which is refreshing the page and component state loses

here is the working example of your code. 
https://codesandbox.io/s/zqww1n3r6l

You can see the reflected changes by inspecting element.

Comment: This isn't correct. If in your `<a>` tag you define `href=#` default browser behavior is to scroll to the top of the window, or to the id of the element that matches the anchor, not refresh the page. To prevent that you add `e.preventDefault()`.

Comment: don't use anchor and e.prevetndefault.

Comment: If you see react docs the best practice is to synthetically bind you listeners and It is considered anti pattern react. I've no issue if you  down vote this. But I would still recommend not to use it. I hope this would help you.

Comment: Then why did I find [this in their documents](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html)?

Comment: There are approached since we have better approached in es6 with babel 7.  We don''t need to dig in to. React is just js we can do everything just like the same way we've been doing in basic html. But react@16 provides such features so don't do this manually.

Comment: Thank you @SakhiMansoor. Whilst I tend to agree for this scenario (in other scenario's I would prefer to use a `div` with `onClick`) it is not the solution to my issue. Neither way works here.

Comment: @Darren your issue is fixed ?

Comment: No, unfortunately not.

Comment: can you add amenitiesData in your post  ?It would be easier to debug the issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178992/discussion-between-sakhi-mansoor-and-darren).